# Struct Attribute on Discriminated Unions

Tags: struct, f#, discriminated-union

I just realized F# records are reference types and how much boxing and unboxing I have going on.  I have a lot of tiny records like this:

```
type InputParam =
    | RegionString of string
    | RegionFloat of float32
```

But if I try to tag it with the "Struct" attribute, I get a compiler error stating "FS3204  If a union type has more than one case and is a struct, then all fields within the union type must be given unique names."  The [language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions) shows to create struct discriminated unions like this:

```
[<Struct>]
type InputParamStruct =
    | RegionString of RegionString: string
    | RegionFloat of RegionFloat: float32
```

What is the difference between x of string and x of x: string? How are the fields not unique to begin with?  Why doesn't F# default to structs for records?

Comment: Note you can see the problem if you look at the decompiled version of the first DU there - RegionString and RegionFloat both end up as classes with a single property "Item" - https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNAJiDUAfALgTwA4FMAEBJAdugK7IAKAhgE7kC22AvALABQ2b2i2ASpgOYCWAe3wBlZJX75e2QWGwRxk3i3YdufIfgBiwQeWQy5YXfoDMAJhXsWAbQA8YykQDGyAHwBdFmix5CJCmoaRxcDJlZ2Th4BYUclQ3UY0UUpEHkU5Qi2KI1hHT0DWUTNfP004wKLIA

Comment: Also, being reference types should _not_ lead to "boxing and unboxing" - If you're truly boxing frequently, there's a different issue in your code. In reality, making this DU a struct would likely significantly reduce performance in your code (since the overall size becomes quite a bit larger than the reference you'd be passing around).

Comment: @ReedCopsey "Item" is just a name though.  If you define the ref type with x of x: string it's functionally identical but swaps the name "Item" for "x".  And how does this not lead to more boxing?  F# composition wraps alot of val types in ref types.

Comment: Ref types stay references - they don't get boxed and unboxed frequently. Item is a hidden name - and the compiler _could_ come up with something different, but doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without question, this should be a struct.  It's immutable and 16 bytes.  Looking at the disassembly, this reference type:

```
type InputParam =
    | RegionString of string
    | RegionFloat of float32
```

And this reference type:

```
type InputParam =
    | RegionString of RegionString: string
    | RegionFloat of RegionFloat: float32
```

Are functionally identical.  The only difference is with how the compiler named things.  They both create a subclass called "RegionString" but with different property names -- "RegionString.item" vs "RegionString.RegionString".

When you convert the first example into a struct, it does away with the subclasses and tries to stick 2 "item" properties on the record which causes the [FS3204](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/3648) unique name error.

As far as performance, you should use structs on every tiny type like these when composing. Consider this example script:

```
type Name = Name of string
let ReverseName (Name s) =
    s.ToCharArray() |> Array.rev |> System.String |> Name

[<Struct>]
type StrName = StrName of string
let StrReverseName (StrName s) =
    s.ToCharArray() |> Array.rev |> System.String |> StrName

#time
Array.init 10000000 (fun x -> Name (x.ToString()))
|> Array.map ReverseName
|> ignore
#time

#time
Array.init 10000000 (fun x -> StrName (x.ToString()))
|> Array.map StrReverseName
|> ignore
#time

sizeof<Name>
sizeof<StrName>
```

The first one wraps a ref type in a ref type which doubled the performance hit:

```
Real: 00:00:04.637, CPU: 00:00:04.703, GC gen0: 340, gen1: 104, gen2: 7
...
Real: 00:00:02.620, CPU: 00:00:02.625, GC gen0: 257, gen1: 73, gen2: 1
...
val it : int = 8
val it : int = 8
```

Functional domain modeling is awesome, but you have to keep in mind that these have the same performance overhead:

```
let c = CustomerID 5
let i = 5 :> obj
```

The recommendation is [anything immutable under 16 bytes should be a struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct).  If it was over 16 bytes, you had to look at the behavior.  If it's being passed around a lot, you might be better off passing the 64-bit ref pointer and taking the ref overhead hit.  But for internal data when composing types or within a function, stick with structs.

Comment: Also worth noting that the size of the data being wrapped by a smaller DU impacts this. With small data, your observation is accurate. With larger data, it ends up being a near-wash since everything is dominated by that data: https://gist.github.com/cartermp/db3a20150b90421d7bd50b65a7fea4ed

Comment: Of course, the % overhead scales down as % work increases, but I'm shocked this isn't stressed as a best practice because overhead = overhead.  Your top level type (Customer) should be a ref type.  It's well over 16 bytes and gets passed around.  But all of the composition types (FName of string, ID of int, Address = { ...}) should all be structs regardless of size since they are fully encapsulated.

Comment: I think it's a good practice that I think can be documented in the F# coding conventions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/conventions

Comment: I added a PR to go into this with a bit more detail: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/16699

Answer (score 13):

Firstly, these aren't Records - they are Discriminated Unions. A Record is a simple aggregate of named data with generated equality/hashing, and making it a struct is also possible but does not come with additional requirements.

The stricter requirements for struct Discriminated Unions are:

- No callable default constructor
- No cyclic references / no recursive definitions
- Multi-case must have unique names

The first two points are inherent to being value types. Value and reference types are just different.

The last point is interesting. Consider the following:

```
type DU1 =
    | Case1 of string
    | Case2 of float

[<Struct>]
type DU2 =
    | Case1 of sval: string
    | Case2 of fval: float
```

In the case of `DU1`, there is an inner class for each case, and those contain properties for accessing the underlying data. These properties are named `Item1`, `Item2`, and so on and since they are encapsulated in an inner class they're unique when accessed.

In the case of `DU2`, the `sval` and `fval` values are laid out flat; there is no inner class that contains them. This is because a goal is performance/size of the struct. The naming strategy for data in a union case (`Item1`/`Item2`/etc.) doesn't apply because all of the data is laid out flat. And so the design decision was to require unique named cases rather than apply some trickery to kludge together the name of the case itself and some variation of `Item1`/`Item2`/etc. The uniqueness issue is inherent to the design of unions themselves in the compiler and not just a codegen design choice.

Lastly, this question has another interesting answer:

> Why doesn't F# default to structs for records?

Tuples, Records, and DUs in F# can all be marked as `[<Struct>]` but are not structs by default. This is because structs are not simply a "make it more efficient" button you can push. Often times you will get worse CPU performance due to excessive copying because your structs are too large. In F#, it is quite normal to have large tuples and very very large records and discriminated unions. Making these structs by default would not be a good choice. Reference types are very powerful and designed to work very well on .NET and shouldn't be avoided by default just because in some cases a struct could result in slightly faster performance.

Whenever you're concerned about performance, never change things just based on assumptions or intuition: use profiling tools like PerfView, dotTrace, or dotMemory; and benchmark small changes with statistical tools like BenchmarkDotNet. Performance is an extremely complicated space and rarely is something simple once you're done accounting for egregious problems that are obviously bad (like O(n^2) algorithms on large data sets or something).

Comment: Okay, ref type is safe by default. It's easy to make things inefficient to copy, but you can't really make something big though.  Strings, lists, arrays, etc are ref types.  

I'm looking at all the boxing that occurs with composition in F# that wouldn't happen in c#, i.e. ref class full of pointers vs a ref class full of value types and pointers.

Comment: Also, take the struct tag off of DU2 and check with dotPeek.  They are functionally identical.  The compiler just sets the name of Case1 of string to "item" and Case1 of Case1: string to "Case1".

Comment: That isn't quite correct. The compiler generates an inner class for each when it's not a struct.

Comment: Yes, without the struct tag they are identical except for the names.  Both create inner classes, except the prop names are DU1.item vs DU2.sval.